# Flutter isn't able to connect to my Java websocket

Tags: java, spring, flutter, websocket

I want my Flutter Web App to be able to communicate with my Java Websocket (using Spring).

My Flutter Web App code:

```
 HtmlWebSocketChannel channel = HtmlWebSocketChannel.connect(Uri(scheme: "ws", host: "locahost", port: 8081, path: "/my-websocket-endpoint"));
 channel.stream.listen((event) { print("Event: " + event.toString());},  onError: (error) => {print(error)});
```

The error I get: `WebSocketChannelException: WebSocket connection failed.`

If I go to my browser and type: `http://localhost:8081/my-websocket-endpoint` I get: `Can "Upgrade" only to "WebSocket".`

My Java code is:

```
    @SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}

    @Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebsocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {





    @Bean
    public WebSocketHandler myMessageHandler() {
        return new MyMessageHandler();
    }


    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(myMessageHandler(), "/my-websocket-endpoint");
    }

}
```

I am still a spring beginner, so I don't know what I've done wrong.
I hope you can help me. If you need more details, just ask.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix my problem:
The only thing I changed was to remove `@Bean` from my code and now it works fine. I do not know why it is working now, but ok... xD